# cakephp How to reset a form to default so previous answers are removed

Tags: cakephp

I have a form to upload images, once submitted i want to do a redirect back to the page to start again, how do I reset the form to default settings?

```
// reset to default settings.
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a redirect, pass them as named params or better as query strings.
this way you can add those to the form as preset values:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    // save etc
} else {
    $this->request->data['ModelName'] = $this->request->query;
}
```

Assuming you are using cake2.3 for example.

PS: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are working with.

Comment: sorry, yes latest cakephp version. As mentioned, wanted to have the form cleared as don't want to give any oppertunity to use same upload twice by just keep pressing 'save button'